# How to replace class component's function.bind(this) in functional component in Reactjs (pagination)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, pagination, this, react-functional-component

Good day. I am building a React crud app with paginations. I intend to use functional components all through. Also, I'm using the the react-js-pagination package for the paginations. I ran into a problem while trying to get the particular link or page number that was clicked. With a class component, I can easily get the value using this: `onChange={this.handlePageChange.bind(this)}`, but with this functional component, I am finding it hard to do. My code is shown below.

The pagination links

``

```
<div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
                <Pagination
                    activePage={activePage}
                    itemsCountPerPage={itemsCountPerPage}
                    totalItemsCount={totalItemsCount}
                    pageRangeDisplayed={3}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        handlePageChange(e.target.value);
                    }}
                    itemClass="page-item"
                    linkClass="page-link"
                />
            </div>
```

``

Now, the handlePageChange Function

``

```
const handlePageChange = async (pageNumber) => {
        console.log(`active page is ${pageNumber}`);
        await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories?page=`+ pageNumber).then(res => {
            setCategories(res.data.data);
            setActivePage(res.data.current_page);
            setItemsCountPerPage(res.data.per_page);
            setTotalItemsCount(res.data.total);
            console.log("yes");
        });    
    }
```

``

When I 'console.log' the pageNumber, it gives me the undefined error. Please, how do I go about this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try this it looks like the page number is passed directly to the `onChange` handler.  No need to use `event.target.value`.  You can see an example of this [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/laughing-brattain-0st2r?file=/src/App.js).  Hope that helps!

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import Pagination from 'react-js-pagination';

export default function App() {
  const activePage = 1
  const itemsCountPerPage = 10
  const totalItemsCount = 52

  const handlePageChange = pageNumber => console.log(pageNumber)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Pagination
        activePage={activePage}
        itemsCountPerPage={itemsCountPerPage}
        totalItemsCount={totalItemsCount}
        pageRangeDisplayed={3}
        onChange={pageNumber => handlePageChange(pageNumber)}
        itemClass="page-item"
        linkClass="page-link"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put `handlePageChange` to `onChange`

```js
const handlePageChange = useCallback((pageNumber) => {
  axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/categories?page=${pageNumber}`)
    .then(({ data: { data, current_page, per_page, total } }) => {
      setCategories(data);
      setActivePage(current_page);
      setItemsCountPerPage(per_page);
      setTotalItemsCount(total);
    })
    .catch(({ message }) => {
      console.error(message);
    });
}, []);
```